# Quels sont les deux mots qui se contractent en « qu'll » ?

Tags: pronoms, contractions

J'ai lu dans Le Petit Prince cette phrase :

> Ainsi, si vous leur dites, « La preuve que le petit prince a existé c'est qu'il était ravissant, qu'll riait, et qu'il voulait un mouton ...

Mais je ne sais pas ce qu'est le mot « qu'll ».

Est-ce que c'est un faute de frappe?

Comment: De frappe, d'OCR, ou d'impression, si c'est sur support papier. Il faut lire « qu'il riait ».

Comment: C'est sur support papier, donc je crois que vous avez raison. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: I'm closing since there's not much to be said about a random glitch.

Comment: If that's the one you used, the title printed on the cover page of this Russian edition should have warned you:  ***Antoiné dé Saint-Exup ry Lê Pêtit Prinçê*** : https://books.google.fr/books?id=oDxtDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false